# stages through coding in C

Tags: c

I'm a really new guy to programming and am trying to learn C through a book which describes that C has 4 primary stages for programming:

- editing
- compiling
- linking
- executing

During the compiling stage it has been mentioned that .obj(extension) files are created. I am not getting the part where any such files are created because it has also been mentioned that the source code must be saved with a .c extension. Therefore, I googled [this link](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/c/mike/misc/compiling_c.html), up and it says compiling has *another* 4 stages, which also says that **header files are created and end in a .h extension**, and I also don't know the point where they are created. Furthermore, creating a binary .exe extension has been mentioned a part of the compiling stage as opposed to the executing stage mentioned in the book I'm following. What are the actual stages of coding and how can I actually view all the types of files created?(I'm using the DEV C++ compiler unable to find a descent compiler particularly for C)

As I've mentioned I'm just a beginner, but I'm curious to know if there would also be a way to view all the machine language code that is actually compiled by the compiler? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You can search about `objcopy` tool i guess.

Comment: This is a lot of questions mashed into one, and may be more suited for other forums like chat or IRC.  To take a stab at answering it, *you* create the `.c` and `.h` files, that's your source code.  The compiler compiles those files into object files.  The linker combines those object files into an executable, which you can run, or a library, which you can't run.  Read the documentation for your compiler to figure out how to get assembly output if you want to see it.  You don't want to look at machine code, almost nobody ever looks at machine code.

Comment: There often is a 5th stage: "- crashing". The more often the less experience the programmer has :-) And those questions are not well suited for stack overflow. Read books, do research, learn and practice, practice, **practice**.

Comment: The most important stage of all - design and specification - is curiously missing as the first item on your list. Pulp the book.

Comment: You are attributing an unhealthy significance to splitting the process into stages.  This is perhaps an echo of the book you are using.  In any case, you write code, then you build an executable (or try to do) using the appropriate process for your particular tools, then you test the result by running it.  But generally you go back and forth among these, and writing (and rewriting, and re-rewriting) the code consumes the lion's share of the time.  You do need to know something about how your tools work, but it's not what you should be focusing on.

Comment: at any point during the compiling phase is it true that an obj file is created(one like any other file that presents itself as an icon with an obj extension)

Answer (score 2):

In reality how a compiler works is more complicated than just 3 or 4 stages.
Usually there are more than 6 phases only for the compiler phase and these are the more standard:

- Lexical Analysis
- Phase Syntax Analysis
- Semantic Analysis Intermediate
- Code Generation
- Code Optimizer
- Code Generation

[image]

For more you can read [here](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/what-is-compiler/) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_phases_of_compiler.htm)

---

Using big-step stages we can split in 4 phases all the process that start from source-code and finish with an executable code:

- Preprocessing:

> In this stage, lines starting with a # character are interpreted by
>   the preprocessor as preprocessor commands.

- Compilation:

> In this stage, the preprocessed code is translated to assembly
>   instructions specific to the target processor architecture. These form
>   an intermediate human readable language.

- Assembly:

> During the assembly stage, an assembler is used to translate the
>   assembly instructions to machine code, or object code.

- Linking:

> The linker will arrange the pieces of object code so that functions in
>   some pieces can successfully call functions in other pieces. It will
>   also add pieces containing the instructions for library functions used
>   by the program.

For more details you can read [here](https://calleerlandsson.com/the-four-stages-of-compiling-a-c-program/)

About your question on how to see Assembly code you can use this command from the terminal:

```
gcc -Wall -S test.c
```

### N.B.

For use gcc command in windows (assuming you are using Dev-c++) just go in the folder `\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin` from the terminal so you can lunch the command.

Answer (score 0):

You first edit the C source file or source files. Files containing executable functions are then saved with a .c extension, and files containing, basically, interface information for those functions are saved with a .h extension.

You then compile, which goes through two important stage, pre-processing, which is essentially program-naive wordprocessing instructions, and compilation proper. Usually the most important step in pre-processing is incorporation of the header into the text of the .c file, though macros and other bits and pieces will also be expanded.

Traditionally C compilers compiled each .c file into a .obj file. However that's less common these days because computers are faster than they were and disks are larger, and an IDE might well hide the obj files from you. The obj file consists of machine code plus symbols for linking. So the functions, now compiled to machine code, together with their names.

The linker then joins all the calls together. It also joins calls to library functions, standard library functions like printf() or extensions like the Windows API. The reason for separating linking from compilation is partly to link libraries, but also because linking is very fast - it's just matching up symbols with addresses - whilst compiling can be slow. So object files are often saved and only recompiled if the actual C source changes.

The linker then creates an executable. The operating system will then load it into memory and run it.

You can examine binary files but they are pretty meaningless except to an expert. Some C compilers allow you to compile to assembly (-S option in gcc), which produces a human-readable representation of the machine code. It's still pretty difficult to follow, and -S is mainly used for small snippets.

An IDE will often create a huge assembly of files which are not meant to be viewed, and are internal to it and hold things like pre-compiled headers, undo states for past edits, current state of the GUI windows, and so on.